# Can't use getText() for double but what to use?

Tags: java

I need my program to set the text in the `textField_price` to the price of the product, but all I get is error. It seems `p.getPrice()` does not work but I have no idea how to fix it??? Have tried a bunch of ways... I understand it's the `setText` that is wrong, since I'm dealing with a double not a String, but I have no clue what to do???

```
    String productName = textField_productName.getText();

    Product p = controller.findProduct(productName);
    if (productName.isEmpty())
        textArea_product.setText("Vänlig fyll i produktnamn.");

    else if (p != null) {
        textField_productName.setText(p.getProductName());
        textField_kategory.setText(p.getKategory())
        textField_price.setText(p.getPrice());

        textArea_product.setText("Produkten " + p.getProductName().toUpperCase() + " hittad.");
    } else {
        textField_price.setText("---");
        textField_kategory.setText("---");
        textArea_product.setText("Produkten med produktnamnet " +  productName  + " hittas ej");
    }
}
```

Comment: "but all I get is error" "does not work" doesn't really tell us anything about problems you are getting, please take a look at http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/. "Have tried a bunch of ways..." is similar, we don't know what exactly did you try and what happened. Maybe you already used suggested approach but there was some other error related to code which you didn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast `double` to `String`

```
textField_price.setText(String.valueOf(p.getPrice()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the number to string  before setting it:

`textField_price.setText(String.valueOf(p.getPrice()));`

Answer (score 0):

First cast your double variable to string like this:

```
textField_price.setText(String.valueOf(p.getPrice()));
```